# Get Azure Log Analytics QueryResults in Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-log-analytics

I am getting a query response from Azure Log Analytics

```
result = log_client.query(myWorkSpaceId, QueryBody(**{'query': 'Heartbeat| limit 50'}))
print (result)
'additional_properties': {}, 'tables': [<azure.loganalytics.models.table_py3.Table object at 0x11011b090>]}
```

This object contains the tables, columns & rows resulting from a query. But how I can get these tables, how do I find names ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to the samples below.

1.Print the tables.

```
print(result.tables)
```

[image]

2.Print the first table.

```
print(result.tables[0])
```

[image]

3.Print the name of the first table.

```
print(result.tables[0].name)
```

[image]

4.Print the first column of the first table.

```
print(result.tables[0].columns[0])
```

[image]

5.Print the first row of the first table.

```
print(result.tables[0].rows[0])
```

[image]